# XCode WorkSpace Files

Tags: ios, xcode

I have to base projects that share several static libraries.  The base projects don't reference each other.  The base projects have files that have the same file name, but are not the same file.  Will this cause issues?  I ask because when I command click on a function, it takes me to a function in the other project.

Can two projects, in the same workspace, have files with the same name as long as they don't reference each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I broke the base projects into their own workspaces.  The workspaces contain the same static libraries.  This fixed the issue where I'd command click a method and xcode would take me to the wrong file (correct file name/method name but wrong project).